# AngularJS and Firebase list details

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been trying to learning AngularJS for the last two weeks, while working on my first todo App..

The problem is that I've now spend days on trying to get the details page to work with Firebase..

When I press a task in the list, I want it to open a details page for the task..

Using the tutorials I can find and writing it into my app have not gone well..I just keep breaking the app and getting blank screen..

I made a plunker sample of the app here:

[Sample App](http://goo.gl/Op7pS0)

Is there a experienced AngularJS coder, that could take quick look and help me getting this to work??

- Thank you..

Comment: No one able to help??

Comment: Your plunker url is broken.